# How to get only <li> tag's innnerHTML from the content having html code

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. Can anyone provide idea how to get li tag innerHTML in array. for example:

```
var content = '<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2
 <ol>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
 </ol>
</li>
<li>Item 5</li>'
```

I want to iterate it such that i can get output as follows:

```
arr[0]='<li>Item 1</li>'
arr[1]='<li>Item 2
 <ol>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
 </ol>
</li>'
arr[2]='<li>Item 5</li>'
```

Moreover, Nested li can also be used similarly by iterating in nested ol.

I want to use something like `document.getElementsByTagName("li");` but it should use only content variable data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it using jQuery

```
var el = $('<div />').append( content  ),
    ar  = [];

el.find('>li').each( function(){
    ar.push(
        $(this).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html()
    )
});

console.log( ar );
```

and print it in console `console.log( ar );`

```
[
 "<li>Item 1</li>" , 
 "<li>Item 2<ol><li>Item ...i>Item 4</li></ol></li>","<li>Item 5</li>" ,
 "<li>Item 5</li>"
]
```

so you can access it ar[0] or 1 .. 2 etc ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using
[JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
</ul>

$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
});
```

A message is thus logged for each item in the list:

0: foo
1: bar

Answer (score 0):

check this out and let me know
http://jsfiddle.net/MrTJM/

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     // Handler for .ready() called.

     $( "li" ).each(function( count ) {
    console.log( count + ": " + $(this).text() );
    });
```

}        );